# AJAX sending array data as JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a form and i wanted specific elements of the form which I got and stored the values in an array.

```
var that = $(this),
url = that.attr('action'),
type = that.attr('method'),

data = {};

var item_name = miniform.elements['itemId'].value;
var quantity = miniform.elements['quantityId'].value;
var amount = miniform.elements['amountId'].value;
var total = amount * quantity;
var cart = ["Item: ",item_name,"Quantity: ",quantity,"Amount: ",amount,"Total: ",total];
```

I would then like to convert this array into a JSON object and send it to a php file through ajax but its not working. Here is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    Content-Type:'application/JSON',
    data: JSON.stringify(cart),
    success: function(){
        console.log('Message Sent');
     }
    });
```

What could be the problem??

Comment: Do you really write `Content-Type:'application/JSON',` because this is a syntax error and would be reported in the console.

Comment: @t.niese what should it be instead??

Comment: @t.niese is the dataType necessary in this context cause I have not included it

Comment: Writing `Context-Text: 'application/JSON'` would cause the script not to run. `Context-Text` is invalid as key, you would need to quote it.

Comment: I see your point @t.niese i removed Context-Text and the code is working however the message is not being displayed in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem and I combined some your responses to find the answer.

```
$('#miniform').on('submit',function(){  
    var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),

    data = {};
    var cart = {};

    cart.item_name = miniform.elements['itemId'].value;
    cart.quantity = miniform.elements['quantityId'].value;
    cart.amount = miniform.elements['amountId'].value;
    cart.total = cart.amount * cart.quantity;

    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(cart);

   $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data:{data:jsonString},
    success: function(){
        console.log('Email Sent');
     },
     error: function(error){
     throw new Error('Did not work');
      }
    });
 return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just send the entire form using `formdata()`. Is there a reason you don't?

Anyway, it doesn't work because you are not creating a json object, but a normal array. There's a difference. You can actually just put the json directly into the ajax call and you don't have to stringify it.

```
var cart = {};
cart['Item'] = item_name;
cart['Quantity'] = quantity;
cart['Amount'] = amount;
cart['Total'] = total;

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://www.google.com',
  type: "POST",
  //Datatype causes it to automatically become json and will expect json back
  //return json back from php through json_encode($myArray);       
  dataType: "json",
  data: cart,
  success: function() {
    alert('Message Sent');
  }
});
```

in short: You used the wrong braces :)

I just changed it to an easier way of managing objects. The problem with your previous object was that it was built wrong. Should be something like:

```
var cart = {"Item":item_name,"Quantity": quantity,"Amount":amount,"Total":total};
```

Comment: A JavaScript object is not JSON. In javascript JSON is a string containing data. And what you assign to `cart` will result in a syntax error.

Comment: Okay I have changed from[] to {} but ajax is still not working

Comment: @lorrainemutheu did you also pay attention to the rest of the ajax call that I've changed and did you mind the quotes?

Comment: @Jonasw not if it's an actual object. With a string, you use quotes. With an object, you don't.

Comment: @Babydead i probably know that. try your own code and youll see that it throws an error, *illegal left hand side expression* probably. thats why you need to use quotes

Comment: @Babydead I have written your exact code for ajax but excluded the Content-Type as it was giving me an error but still the message is not being displayed in the console.

Comment: @lorrainemutheu sorry, i forgot to change the `:` in the json object. They shouldn't be within the quotes but in between the name and the value. Please see my updated answer. Sorry for the slow replies, I'm not at home. I also removed the content-type header. I feel like it's not really necessary

Answer (score 0):

you are doing wrong .

please use this way

```
var cart = {"Item ":item_name,"Quantity ":quantity,"Amount ":amount,"Total ":total};

$.ajax({
url: url,
type: type,
Content-Type:'application/JSON',
data: JSON.parse(cart),
success: function(){
    console.log('Message Sent');
 }
});
```

If you want to post the array Then you can use this way.

```
cart = [];
cart[0] = item_name;
cart[1] = quantity;
cart[2] = amount;
cart[3] = total;

$.ajax({
url: url,
type: type,
Content-Type:'application/JSON',
data:{cart:cart},
success: function(){
    console.log('Message Sent');
 }
});
```

Comment: oh !! sorry , it's typing mistake , i will correct it.

Comment: @vjytiwari I have used your first method but the data is still not being sent.....or maybe there is a problem with the first part of the code with $(this)

Answer (score 0):

look the comma, it should be `{"key":value, "key":value..}` not `{"key":,value, "key":,value..}`

```
var cart = {"Item" : item_name, "Quantity" : quantity, "Amount" : amount, "Total" : total};
```

Answer (score 0):

### Don't build it manually

Instead of building your Object or Array manually, which is prone to errors, do it like this:

### Object

```
// Define your empty Object
var cart = {};

// Assign its properties
cart.item_name = miniform.elements['itemId'].value;
cart.quantity = miniform.elements['quantityId'].value;
cart.amount = miniform.elements['amountId'].value;
cart.total = amount * quantity;
```

### Array

Or if you prefer to have an array:

```
// Define your empty array
var cart = [];

// Assign its properties
cart['item_name'] = miniform.elements['itemId'].value;
cart['quantity'] = miniform.elements['quantityId'].value;
cart['amount'] = miniform.elements['amountId'].value;
cart['total'] = amount * quantity;
```

Now you have your `cart` Object or Array ready and you can call `JSON.stringify` on it:

```
JSON.stringify(cart);
```

Comment: please could you add the ajax code for the code above cause that's where am stuck